# MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission Andriod 11

Tags: android

I recently launched my app on the google play store and it was rejected because I declare the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission which I need to access photos in android 11 and above. So my question is there any other way to access photos without this permission in android 11 and above

Comment: How are you accessing fotos at the moment? As there are so many ways .

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to open the "**All Files Access** " for your app

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

I used media store firstly but it's not working on android 11 and further more 12 ,13.

But it might be a chance to reject the application on the play console but you can modify it on the console that (Core functionality or app functionality)
Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

remove MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE from AndroidManifest.xml and try with bellow code

```
<application
        
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" // add this line
// ADD THIS
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:initOrder="100"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provide_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**provide_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: Do I need to edit my code to use this

Comment: yes, it's worked for me, same play store issue i faced.

Comment: What is requestLegacyExternalStorage?
Apps that run on Android 11 but target Android 10 (API level 29) can still request the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute. This flag allows apps to temporarily opt out of the changes associated with scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and different types of media files

So, this solution will not work on latest devices because in new version The flag "requestLegacyExternalStorage" is ignored

Answer (score 0):

You can query the MediaStore for images.

You can use ACTION_PICK, ACTION_GET_CONTENT, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select -multiple- images.

You can use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick a directory containing pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SAF framework, which needs no permissions at all, It involves user to select image using System picker

```
// Request code for selecting a PDF document.
const val PICK_IMG = 2
fun openFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "image/*"

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the file that should appear in the
        // system file picker when it loads.
        // putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMG)
}
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMG


        && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
        // the user selected.
        resultData?.data?.also { uri ->

            val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            // Check for the freshest data.
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
            // you can get uri and perform any function on it
            // Perform operations on the document using its URI.
        }
    }
}

fun dumpImageMetaData(uri: Uri) {

    // The query, because it only applies to a single document, returns only
    // one row. There's no need to filter, sort, or select fields,
    // because we want all fields for one document.
    val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
        uri, null, null, null, null, null)

    cursor?.use {
        // moveToFirst() returns false if the cursor has 0 rows. Very handy for
        // "if there's anything to look at, look at it" conditionals.
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {

            // Note it's called "Display Name". This is
            // provider-specific, and might not necessarily be the file name.
            val displayName: String =
                it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
            Log.i(TAG, "Display Name: $displayName")

            val sizeIndex: Int = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
            // If the size is unknown, the value stored is null. But because an
            // int can't be null, the behavior is implementation-specific,
            // and unpredictable. So as
            // a rule, check if it's null before assigning to an int. This will
            // happen often: The storage API allows for remote files, whose
            // size might not be locally known.
            val size: String = if (!it.isNull(sizeIndex)) {
                // Technically the column stores an int, but cursor.getString()
                // will do the conversion automatically.
                it.getString(sizeIndex)
            } else {
                "Unknown"
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Size: $size")
        }
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun getBitmapFromUri(uri: Uri): Bitmap {
    val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor =
        contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
    val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor
    val image: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
    parcelFileDescriptor.close()
    return image
}
```

Java Version

```
 // Request code for selecting a PDF document.
private static final int PICK_IMG = 2;

private void openFile(Uri pickerInitialUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the file that should appear in the
    // system file picker when it loads.
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMG);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMG

            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
        // the user selected.
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
                    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        // Check for the freshest data.
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);

            // Perform operations on the document using its URI.
        }
    }
}

public void dumpImageMetaData(Uri uri) {

    // The query, because it only applies to a single document, returns only
    // one row. There's no need to filter, sort, or select fields,
    // because we want all fields for one document.
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
            .query(uri, null, null, null, null, null);

    try {
        // moveToFirst() returns false if the cursor has 0 rows. Very handy for
        // "if there's anything to look at, look at it" conditionals.
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            // Note it's called "Display Name". This is
            // provider-specific, and might not necessarily be the file name.
            String displayName = cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.i(TAG, "Display Name: " + displayName);

            int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
            // If the size is unknown, the value stored is null. But because an
            // int can't be null, the behavior is implementation-specific,
            // and unpredictable. So as
            // a rule, check if it's null before assigning to an int. This will
            // happen often: The storage API allows for remote files, whose
            // size might not be locally known.
            String size = null;
            if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex)) {
                // Technically the column stores an int, but cursor.getString()
                // will do the conversion automatically.
                size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
            } else {
                size = "Unknown";
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Size: " + size);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i don't really understand kotlin is there any way you write it in java

Comment: yeah sure I will add java version as well